# Slider revolution touch swipe moves the whole page on IOS devices

Tags: css, revolution-slider

Its working fine on android but on IOS, if you swipe left or right, the entire page moves.

I tried using the following code but it's not working:

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
body, html{
    touch-action: pan-y;
}
}
```

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: Not enough shared. Host the code either on CodePen/JSFiddle or create a snippet here that reproduces the problem

Comment: its the wordpress plugin Revolution slider with touch swipe enabled